# mount + copy files to mounted directory how to enable?

Tags: mount

with the following mount command I can copy from 10.112.12.180 any file to the linux machine (/mnt)

```
    mount -t nfs 10.112.12.180:/dir1/dir2/dir /mnt
```

my question if it possible to perform the other side: to copy from linux machine to 10.112.12.180 server

I try it but I get

```
 cp file /mnt
 cp: cannot create regular file `/mnt/file: Read-only file system
```

how to get solution for this (copy from linux to server?)

mount + copy files to mounted directory is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS can be quite tricky.

You should check */etc/exports* file at the *10.112.12.180* and see if the share has been setup with read+write permissions (rw). A correct /etc/exports line should be something like

```
/dir1/dir2/dir xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(rw)
```

... where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP address (range) for your allowed NFS clients.

Also NFS might shoot you to the foot if you're trying to copy files as a different user than the one owning the NFS share.

Comment: my /etc/exports is empty files? what I need to do?

Comment: What, the /etc/exports at the 10.112.12.180 is empty and it still allows you to mount some NFS share? What distribution are you using and what tool you have used to setup that 10.112.12.180? 

If NFS seems to be too much hassle, you might want to consider copying via ssh (using scp or rsync).

Comment: the server 10.112.12.180 is windows server not linux

Comment: Oh, that changes the game a bit. I have no idea how to configure NFS in Windows. :) 

Samba is a way much more used approach when it comes to filesharing between Windows and Linux/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `/sbin/mount-copybind /tmp/mnt2 /mnt2/` then try copy command